# Dialog crashing when TextView set

Tags: java, android

I have the following code which is called by the onClick event of buttons contained within a ListView.

```
public void viewExerciseHistory(View view) {
    // History button click handler
    LinearLayout parentRow = (LinearLayout)view.getParent();

    TextView exerciseNameTextView = (TextView)parentRow.getChildAt(0);
    String exerciseName = (String)exerciseNameTextView.getText();

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.exercise_history_dialog);
    dialog.setTitle(exerciseName);

    TextView headerTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.exercise_history_dialog_name_textview);
    //headerTextView.setText("History");

    Button closeDialogButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.exercise_history_dialog_close_button);
    //closeDialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    //  @Override
    //  public void onClick(View v) {
    //      dialog.dismiss();
    //  }
    //});

    dialog.show();
}
```

The ListView row is defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/exercise_history_dialog_name_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/exercise_history_dialog_close_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/button_blue_text"
        android:text="@string/button_text_close"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The above code works fine and displays the dialog, but if uncomment out the `headerTextView.setText("History")` or the `closeDialog.setOnClickListener` it crashes with a NullPointerException.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

*EDIT* LogCat:

```
10-14 21:36:19.755: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26167): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
10-14 21:36:19.755: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26167): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
10-14 21:36:19.915: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26167): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
10-14 21:36:19.945: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26167): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
10-14 21:36:20.435: D/AndroidRuntime(26167): Shutting down VM
10-14 21:36:20.435: W/dalvikvm(26167): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e27930)
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167):    ... 11 more
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167):    at com.example.workoutlog.ManageWorkouts.viewExerciseHistory(ManageWorkouts.java:269)
10-14 21:36:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(26167):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Please post a Logcat.

Comment: Your error is on line 269 of the Manageworkouts class in the method you posted above.  What's on that line?

Comment: That line is the headerTextView.setText("History"); part, if I comment that out it works then the dialog does display

Comment: because headerTextView and closeDialogButton are null

Comment: And is that your ListView row xml, or your dialog's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's crashing because this line:

```
TextView headerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exercise_history_dialog_name_textview);
```

is actually returning null.

The findViewById method is looking for the view on the main activity's content view. Instead you want to use the findViewById method on the view object. Calling findViewById on the view object will allow you to get the fields you are after.

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.exercise_history_dialog);

TextView headerTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.exercise_history_dialog_name_textview);
headerTextView.setText("History");
```

Comment: Excellent, that's fixed it. Makes perfect sense now you've said it, thanks for your help

Comment: after setContentView, you can use the dialog itself to findViewById. There is no need to inflate the dialog's view first like this

Comment: Ah right enough. I never noticed that the dialog had a findByViewMethod. I'll edit the code to make it cleaner.

Comment: Also if you're going to actually inflate the View, you might as well setContentView with dialog_view.

Comment: There, now it looks like my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing these

```
TextView headerTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.exercise_history_dialog_name_textview);
Button closeDialogButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exercise_history_dialog_close_button);
```

to

```
TextView headerTextView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.exercise_history_dialog_name_textview);
Button closeDialogButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.exercise_history_dialog_close_button);
```

You have to tell which view you want to `findViewById` from